# Can we find a countable subset of the real numbers which give us an outer jordan measure 1 but lebesgue 0?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, lebesgue-measure

I want to know how to construct, thanks.(I'm a newbie to math)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any set that is Jordan measurable has Jordan measure that agrees with its Lebesgue measure.

However, if you mean a set that has outer Jordan measure $1$ and Lebesgue measure $0$, consider $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$.